# Databricks Invalid token when using proxy/no_proxy

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have an Azure Machine Learning Compute Instance where I do pyspark code to a databricks cluster.

I have to use a proxy configuration from my company, but I don't need the proxy to access my databricks (an other ressources) since they are the in same subscription/ressource group/Spoke.

When I don't set my `https_proxy`, my query runs. But when is set my `https_proxy` with this `no_proxy`, it fails.

> export no_proxy=export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,.if.atcsg.net,.adf.azure.com,.afs.azure.net,.agentsvc.azure-automation.net,.analysis.windows.net,.api.azureml.ms,.applicationinsights.azure.com,.azconfig.io,.azmk8s.io,.aznbcontent.net,.azure-api.net,.azure-automation.net,.azurecr.io,.azuredatabricks.net,.azure-devices.net,.azure-devices-provisioning.net,.azurehdinsight.net,.azurestaticapps.net,.azuresynapse.net,.azurewebsites.net,.backup.windowsazure.com,.batch.azure.com,.blob.core.windows.net,.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com,.cognitiveservices.azure.com,.database.windows.net,.datafactory.azure.net,.dev.azuresynapse.net,.developer.azure-api.net,.dfs.core.windows.net,.dicom.azurehealthcareapis.com,.digitaltwins.azure.net,.directline.botframework.com,.documents.azure.com,.europe.directline.botframework.com,.europe.token.botframework.com,.eventgrid.azure.net,.fhir.azurehealthcareapis.com,.file.core.windows.net,.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com,.guestconfiguration.azure.com,.his.arc.azure.com,.inference.ml.azure.com,.instances.azureml.ms,.kubernetesconfiguration.azure.com,.kusto.windows.net,.managedhsm.azure.net,.mariadb.database.azure.com,.media.azure.net,.mongo.cosmos.azure.com,.monitor.azure.com,.mysql.database.azure.com,.notebooks.azure.net,.ods.opinsights.azure.com,.oms.opinsights.azure.com,.openai.azure.com,.pbidedicated.windows.net,.postgres.database.azure.com,.prod.migration.windowsazure.com,.purview.azure.com,.queue.core.windows.net,.redis.cache.windows.net,.redisenterprise.cache.azure.net,.scm.azurewebsites.net,.search.windows.net,.service.batch.azure.com,.service.signalr.net,.servicebus.windows.net,.siterecovery.windowsazure.com,.sql.azuresynapse.net,.table.core.windows.net,.table.cosmos.azure.com,.tip1.powerquery.microsoft.com,.token.botframework.com,.vault.azure.net,.vaultcore.azure.net,.web.core.windows.net,.workspace.azurehealthcareapis.com,azure-automation.net,azurecr.io,database.windows.net,sql.azuresynapse.net

I have `.azuredatabricks.net` in my `no_proxy` which work for SQL warehouses queries, but not for pyspark using databricks clusters.

Any idea on which domain I have to set to my `no_proxy` for `databricks-connect` to communicate with my cluster?

## Update

So I found a solution, that seems dirty, is it a good workaround, I'd rather know the correct no_proxy domain that this workaround.

```py
import os
from pyspark import SparkConf

# Backup the current value of https_proxy
https_proxy_backup = os.environ.get("https_proxy", "")

# Temporarily remove the https_proxy variable
if "https_proxy" in os.environ:
    del os.environ["https_proxy"]

try:
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
except:
    pass
finally:
    os.environ["https_proxy"] = https_proxy_backup
```

Comment: It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Comment: I don't think it's a correct solution, but a workaround. Spark options should accept to not use proxy env variable. There's a java option for this, but I didn't make it work. Thus still asking for a real solution rather than this patch that will confuse anyone reading the code.